# Centralizers in non-abelian groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a non-abelian group. Assume that for every two non-central elements $x$ and $y$ there is a non-central element  $w \in C_G(x) ‎‎\cap‎ C_G(y)$. Then what can we say about $G$?

Comment: Do you ask this because of your interest in the *commuting graphs* of groups? There seems to be no (finite?) group known to have this property - see [the last sentence here](http://symomega.wordpress.com/2010/03/02/commuting-graphs-of-groups/).

Comment: @Someone: One of the comments on that same blog post mentions that there is a group of order 32 whose commuting graph has diameter 2.

Comment: @S. Carnahan: Oh, right. Thanks. Even the very first comment corrects already the statement that no such groups are known. It seems worth to read the comments sometimes...